# How to remove Double Quote in JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json

I searched through this forum but did not get similar case of removing double quotes in JSON array.
This is my part request format

"customer_address_list":[{"email_address" :{"email_to" : ""},
                          "method" : "EMAIL",
                          "customer_id" : ""}]

As this is dynamic values I putting values with push of JSON in for loop. Something like this in  my js

Request_Format.customer_address_list.push( XXXXXXXXXXX) ;

Every time there is unwanted double quotes appending in every entry like

"customer_address_list":[
**"**{"email_address":"email_to":"xyz.pqqr@companyname.com"},"method":"EMAIL","customer_id":"1"}**"**,
**"**{"email_address":"email_to":"zzz.aaaa@companyname.com"},"method":"EMAIL","customer_id":"2"}**"**,
**"**{email_address":"email_to":"www.aaaa@companyame.com"},"method":"EMAIL","customer_id":"3"}**"**]

Due to this additional double quote at start and end of every entry, Final JSON became invalid.

All above code shared is in java script
Is there any work around to remove this double quotes
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this in java? Python?

Comment: Please reformat your code for better readability

Comment: Formatting done. We are using java but code I shared is from javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, you can convert each string to a dictionary  literal using the eval function

```
customer_as_dict = eval(customer_as_string)
```

To remove the quotes around the name customer_address_list, you may be able to use

```
eval("customer_address_list") = [eval(customer_as_string) for customer_as_string in dict_as_string]
```